# PHP - Domain to IP

Tags: php

I current have a system which works like this:

Insert IP and it will post the IP to another .php page. However, when I try post http://google.com it does not turn the domain into a IP.

How would I do that? E.g. when a user inserts http://google.com or any domain it will auto resolve the IP.

I know the function gethostbyadd, I dont know how to structure it out e.g. Forms, table, post data.

Thanks if any can help.

Comment: how about showing what you got already.

Comment: Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/E7s57Eak

Answer (score 12):

What have you got together so far? How is it failing?

A wild guess is that you're typing in http://google.com/ and trying to get an IP from that, and that will fail, as the URL contains protocol information as well. You need to pass the domain name, and **only the domain name** to gethostbyname:

```
gethostbyname('www.google.com'); // Works
gethostbyname('http://www.google.com'); // Will not work
```

If you have the protocol part (http://) in the beginning, you can use parse_url:

```
gethostbyname(parse_url('http://www.google.com', PHP_URL_HOST));
```

If you're having some other, specific problem, let us know. If you don't know where to start, I suggest start by reading up on a programming manual ;)

Comment: It's not only google, it depends on the person whatever URL he puts. I need a simple form that auto resolves domain to IP.

Answer (score 9):

I think you're looking for [`gethostbyname`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php):

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.google.com');
```

Note, make sure you strip the http:// and any white space/trailing characters as this will likely prevent accurate results.

Comment: This is very important to strip http, since otherwise it just returns the url (function argument)

Answer (score 1):

the function you are looking for is [$x = gethostbyname('stackoverflow.com');](http://bg.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

Comment: Nope, basically its a form when I insert domainname it should auto resolve the domain to IP. It's a post data method.

Comment: Raymond your comment makes no sense. The suggestion Aviatrix and the others have given are spot on.

Comment: Basically, when a person enters there own domain or other domain names into the "host" box it should auto resolve the domain into a IP. So they dont have to ping to get the IP. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/E7s57Eak

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to look into using http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php

Answer (score 1):

In some people the function `gethostbyname` is running slowly or running once in a while. Some say that the apache needs rebooting to get the function started. I can not confirm this, but I want to give an alternative method how to find IP by Domain using `nslookup`

```
function getAddrByHost($host, $timeout = 1) {
   $query = `nslookup -timeout=$timeout -retry=1 $host`;
   if(preg_match('/\nAddress: (.*)\n/', $query, $matches))
      return trim($matches[1]);
}

echo getAddrByHost('example.com');
```

speed test using XHProf:

*attempt 1*

gethostbyname 5,014,593 microsec

getAddrByHost 29,656 microsec

*attempt 2*

gethostbyname 5,016,678 microsec

getAddrByHost 13,887 microsec

*attempt 3*

gethostbyname 5,014,640 microsec

getAddrByHost 8,297 microsec

Conclusion: the function `gethostbyname` is performed for more than 5 seconds, which is very long. Therefore, I advise you to use a faster function `getAddrByHost`

note: php use this file `/etc/resolv.conf` to get DNS servers:

In my case I use BIND (named) which works on the host 127.0.0.1

```
# /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: This is a low quality answer that has been flagged for deletion. Please add information besides the code to help the person asking understand how this solution works, as well as future visitors to this question.

Comment: This is indeed a very good answer. This will get you the ip address realy good. gethostbyname hat multiple issues in complex infrastructures.

Note that the ` syntax is very old and not working anymore.